# Customization of model class name display in Admin and __unicode__ multiple return

Tags: python, django

In my models.py , this is my class structure :

```
class Department_master(ModelWithoutAppName):
    rec_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    department_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    FALSE = '0'
    TRUE = '1'
    Status_choices = (
        (TRUE, 'True'),             
        (FALSE, 'False'),        

    )

    status=models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=Status_choices,
                                  default=TRUE)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.department_name
```

Now I have registered this model in Admin(admin.py) by:

```
 admin.site.register(Department_master)
```

Now when I am going to admin to view details ,first of all it is showing :

```
 Department_masters (the model class name)
```

And when I click on Department_masters:

```
Department_master (the model class name)
Testing (added department_name in the table department_master  as my __unicode__ returns self.department_name)
```

Now I want to change my model class name viewing in Admin section presently

```
Department_master to  Department Master.
```

And also want to show not just

```
department_name under Department_master
```

also

```
department_code by modifying __unicode__ return
```

is it possible?

Comment: I got the second part answer :                                    class Department_masterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   
    list_display = ('department_code', 'department_name')

Comment: Got the 1st Answer also , Using Meta you can do this :                   class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Department Master'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Department Masters'